# How to adjust all elements in the line to the height of the dynamic image?

Tags: dart, flutter

There is a Row in it two blocks: a picture and a Column. There are several blocks in the Column: heading, text and price. There is a fixed width for the image, thanks to which the image is scaled and stretches the string with its height. How can I lower the block with the price down to the bottom edge of the picture?

[image]

```dart
  Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 16
                ),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/photo.jpg',
                      width: 160
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                            child: Text(
                              "Wonderful haircut",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            "An undercut is typecally a cut done with clippers in the back.",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 16),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                              "\$50",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Colors.white
                              )
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `spaceBetween` option of `MainAxisAlignment` with your `Column` widget:

```
            Expanded(
            child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                  //reminder of your column code

                ),
              ),
            ),
```

The reason is your `Column` height will be the same as its parent `Row`, which has its size determined by the `Image` height.And as the `Column` children can't fill the whole space, an empty space remains at the end. Which is now distributed equally between its `children`. You can play around with other options such as `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`.

Comment: It does not work as the Container does not stretch to the height of the picture. https://imgur.com/KTQKyW5